# Can I send a .xml file from .py script to .php script without using API

Tags: php, python, xml

I am stuck in my project work.

I have to send a .xml file from my python script to .php script without using any API.

What method/modules can I use for this purpose?

The PHP script after receiving the file should ask the user for downloading and download it from browser.

Please guide me with some ideas.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I think you have to create a small python server serving the xml file. https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Comment: Why not save XML to disk from Python and read into PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can :)
read about xml RPC:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html

http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php

Answer (score 0):

If Python and PHP are equipped on same server, consider a straightforward file export/import where the xml content is converted to string and saved as file from Python and then read into PHP:

**Python**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlstr = '''\
    <data>      
        <example>88</example>        
    </data>'''    
dom = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)

tree_out = ET.tostring(dom, encoding='UTF-8', method='xml')
xmlfile = open('/path/to/Output.xml', 'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**PHP**

```
// LOAD XML SOURCE
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('/path/to/Output.xml');

// ECHO CONTENT
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

---

**Command Line**

You can even call the Python script via command line from PHP using `exec()`:

```
exec('python /path/to/Python/Script.py');

// LOAD XML SOURCE
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('/path/to/Output.xml');    

// ECHO CONTENT
echo $doc->saveXML();

//<?xml version="1.0"?>
//<data>      
//        <example>88</example>        
//    </data>
```

And vice versa from Python using subprocess's `call` or `Popen`

```
import subprocess

#... same as above ...

# RUN CHILD PROCESS W/O OUTPUT
subprocess.call(['php', '/path/to/PHP/Script.php'])

# RUN CHILD PROCESS W/ OUTPUT
proc = subprocess.Popen(['php','/path/to/PHP/Script.php'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()

print(stdout.decode("utf-8"))

#<?xml version="1.0"?>
#<data>      
#        <example>88</example>        
#    </data>
```